# How to obtain a file object from a variable or from http URL without actually creating a file?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-io, pypdf

I want to manipulate a downloaded PDF using PyPDF and for that, I need a file object.

I use GAE to host my Python app, so I cannot actually write the file to disk.

Is there any way to obtain the file object from URL or from a variable that contains the file contents?

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most tools (including `urllib`) already give you a file-like, but if you need true random access then you'll need to create a [`StringIO.StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) and read the data into it.

Comment: Now I see you answer is the best on what he is asking.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I am now stuck trying to un-botch the file that I am receiving from a Javascript frontend, but that's another story. I will folow up and mark the answers as soon as I get to test the both options with PyPDF and an actual file.

Comment: Well, from what I've learned about StringIO to date, it's a really good way to go with handling files in my context. I will redesign my code to use StringIO. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In GAE you can use the blobstore to read, write file data and to upload and download files. And you can use the File API:

Example :

```
_file = files.blobstore.create(mime_type=mimetype, _blobinfo_uploaded_filename='test')
with files.open(_file, 'a') as f :                                                      
    f.write(somedata)                                                         
files.finalize(_file)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm a casual programmer with only a superficial understanding so these pieces of advice are valuable to me regardless of whether I use them to solve the current issue.